# Weakly convergent subsequence under continuous operator

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose we have two Hilbert spaces $H_1,~ H_2$, a linear continuous operator $T:H_1 \to H_2$ and a weakly convergent sequence $u_k\rightharpoonup u$ in $H_1$.

Is $Tu_k \rightharpoonup Tu$ in $H_2$ true? If yes, could you give me a short sketch of the proof?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Hint: T has an adjoint.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Your assertion is true even in Banach spaces.